# can any identity involving integers be proved by mathematical induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Hello mathematics community,

Today I was studying mathematical induction which is an axiom.

I was wondering

1. Can "ANY" identity or inequality involving integers which is already proven can also be proved by mathematical induction?
2. Are there any theorems which can only be  proved using mathematical induction?

3.As far as I know we have first principle of mathematical induction, second principle of mathematical induction

Do we have nth principle of mathematical induction also, if yes can I know problems involving it.(n value being larger upto 10 or even more).

I dont know what tags are to be kept for this question....

Thankyou for your valuable time.

**EDIT**

I have found the answer for the third question and the example of such a problem is to prove the that the number of triangles in a triangulation of polygon of n sides is n-2. Here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9sYIWHIvNc

Comment: What do you mean by $n$-th principle of mathematical induction?

Comment: If you found an example for part of your question, you should either edit it into the question, or submit it as an answer.  These discussions are not _only_ for the question submitter.

Comment: I meant the extended principle of mathematical induction @user170039

Comment: edited the question @Slade

Comment: The two forms of induction are usually given by (1): if you have proved "for every $n$, if $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$" and also $P(0)$, then $P(n)$ is true for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. And (2): if "for every $n$, if $P(m)$ is true for every $m < n$, then $P(n)$" and also $P(0)$, then again $P$ is true for all $n$. Formulation (2) is known as *complete induction*. [An induction starting at, say, $n=10$ is easily turned into case (1) by writing $k = n - 10$ and substituting.]

Comment: The answer to your question (2) is very nearly "yes", because the natural numbers (= the set of non-negative integers) are *defined* by the Peano axioms [see Wikipedia]. These say, in essence, (i) that $0$ is a number, (ii) if $n$ is a number then $n+1$ is a number, and (iii) that induction works. And any proof about natural numbers has to be derived from these axioms. So apart from a few statements like "$\forall n (n + 1 \neq 0)$" derived from the non-inductive axioms [1-8 on the Wikipedia page], every theorem uses induction everywhere. Even the proof that $\forall x\forall y (x+y = y+x)$.

Comment: Can you add the principle of mathematical induction, nth principle  of mathemactical induction and the extended principle of mathematicla induction to  your post?

Answer (score 2):

As a logical matter, the answer to 1. is yes, since any proof could be inserted into an inductive proof. As a practical matter, the answer is no, since some proofs about integers are best proven using fields in which integers are embedded (real or complex numbers, for example).

The answer to 2. is yes, if you mean "require the assumptions that induction uses". In particular, when using mathematical induction on integers we assume the set of natural numbers is well ordered (every nonempty subset has a least element). This assumption is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: can you give an example for the second one

Comment: For further discussion see https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Gillman544-553.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here is an integer identity which can easily be proved, but not by induction:

$$p\in\mathbb{P}\implies[p=2]\vee[p=3]\vee[p\equiv\pm1\pmod6]$$

However, I have no idea how to prove that it cannot be proved by induction.